# mysql-user created/granted but no connection via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, phpmyadmin

I have logged in to my debian-server via SSH and then in MySQL with root.

Then I have created a new database with **CREATE DATABASE new_db;**

and finally a new user with **GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on new_db.* to 'new_user'@'%' identified by 'mypassword';**

at last I made **FLUSH PRIVILEGES**;

when I no try to connect to the DB with phpmyadmin (which runs on my local machine) it says '*connection refused (check your host, user, password...)*'

i can login with my new user in via mysql-console in SSH, but not in phpmyadmin(?)

what did I worng? is there something I forgot?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was my fault :/

I had a transposed number in the IP

anyway.. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

> > > when I no try to connect to the DB with phpmyadmin (which runs on my local machine) it say

You have created the database in debian-server, so you must use this server ip address to access the phpmyadmin.

Comment: I do .. in the config.inc.php of phpmyadmin I have added the IP of the debian-server, the new user and password